# Deploy Failed Due to error Value of property Variables must be an object with String (or simple type) properties

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I am getting a serverless error as follow:
An error occurred: CandidateSubmissionLambdaFunction - Value of property Variables must be an object with String (or simple type) properties.

I have tried changing the value to string from a yml file then also I am getting the same error.

My Yml file code is as below:

```
frameworkVersion: ">=1.1.0 <2.0.0"

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs8.10
  stage: dev
  region: us-east-1
  environment:
    CANDIDATE_TABLE: ${self:service}-${opt:stage, self:provider.stage}
    CANDIDATE_EMAIL_TABLE: "candidate-email-${opt:stage, self:provider.stage}"
    iamRoleStatements:
      - Effect: Allow
        Action:
          - dynamodb:Query
          - dynamodb:Scan
          - dynamodb:GetItem
          - dynamodb:PutItem
        Resource: "*"

resources:
  Resources:
    CandidatesDynamoDbTable:
      Type: 'AWS::DynamoDB::Table'
      DeletionPolicy: Retain
      Properties:
        AttributeDefinitions:
          -
            AttributeName: "id"
            AttributeType: "S"
        KeySchema:
          -
            AttributeName: "id"
            KeyType: "HASH"
        ProvisionedThroughput:
          ReadCapacityUnits: 1
          WriteCapacityUnits: 1
        StreamSpecification:
          StreamViewType: "NEW_AND_OLD_IMAGES"
        TableName: ${self:provider.environment.CANDIDATE_TABLE}

functions:
  candidateSubmission:
    handler: api/candidate.submit
    memorySize: 128
    description: Submit candidate information and starts interview process.
    events:
      - http:
          path: candidates
          method: post
```

Environment Information

```
     OS:   linux
     Node Version:  8.10.0
     Serverless Version: 1.27.3
```

I want to deploy this on aws and want to perform curd operation.

Answer (score 2):

One of the variables used for value in your YAML configuration might be the wrong type.

`${self:service}` isn't defined in the YAML but is being referenced in

```
provider:
  environment:
    CANDIDATE_TABLE: ${self:service}-${opt:stage, self:provider.stage}
```